# Using a non-default key name (other than id_rsa)

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have set the Github passwordless login as below.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa  -P ''  
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub  |xclip
```

I pasted the public key into **ssh and gpg keys** on the Github site.

```
git init  
git config --global user.name "someone"  
git config --global user.email  "sbd@gmail.com"  
git config remote.origin.url git+ssh://git@github.com/someone/newstart.git  
ssh -T git@github.com  
git clone  git+ssh://git@github.com/someone/newstart.git   /tmp/newstart
```

The above works.

Now I want to use a different key name for Github instead of its default name **id_rsa**.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa  -P ''  -f  .ssh/id_rsa.github
cat .ssh/id_rsa.github.pub  |xclip
```

I pasted the new pub key into **ssh and gpg keys** on the Github site.

```
git init  
git config --global user.name "someone"  
git config --global user.email  "sbd@gmail.com"  
git config remote.origin.url git+ssh://git@github.com/someone/newstart.git  
ssh -T git@github.com
```

The above does not work.

```
git clone  git+ssh://git@github.com/someone/newstart.git   /tmp/newstart
```

The above also does not work.

```
ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa.github -T git@github.com
```

The command above can connect to Github successfully, but I can't type the following command to clone the repository.

```
git clone  -i  .ssh/id_rsa.github  git+ssh://git@github.com/someone/newstart.git   /tmp/newstart
```

Can't I use a pub key with another name, such as **id_rsa.github** instead of the default name **id_rsa**?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to tell SSH to use this key for Github. Put this in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.github
    User git
```

**EDIT**:

I want to address those in the comments saying that Github or Gitlab "ignore" the `HostName` and only use `Host`. That's not quite correct.

The opening line of these blocks, the `Host` line, is one or more hostname patterns that define when the rest of the block is applied. For example, you could say:

```
Host bitbucket bitbucket.org holymoly
    HostName bitbucket.org
    User git
```

What this says is:

1. If ssh is called with a target hostname of `bitbucket`, `bitbucket.org`, or `holymoly`, then apply the following two properties:
2. First, connect to `bitbucket.org` no matter which of the 3 names the user specified on the commandline; they are just aliases
3. Second, the username for this connection is `git`.

This is the distinction between `Host` and `HostName`.

Note that in the above, if `bitbucket.org` weren't even in the `Host` line, you could still tell ssh to connect to `holymoly` and you'd end up connected to bitbucket.org.

`Host` is a list of names and/or patterns that you can specify in your SSH command, that will trigger this block to match at all.

`HostName` is the **real** hostname to use, in the event that the one in `Host` is not the real hostname. If you don't supply a `HostName`, then the value of `Host` is used as the default value.

You can use patterns for `Host` as well.

```
Host *.mydomain.com
    HostName proxy.mydomain.com
```

Here, no matter what you put as the hostname, if it's in the `mydomain.com` domain name, it will actually connect to the proxy hostname specified.

I hope that helps explain the difference, and makes my original answer less confusing.

Comment: This works thanks! It's weird that GitHub doesn't take the `Hostname` directive from ssh config file (they only take Host directive as you exemplified above), whereas Bitbucket.org (or bitbucket.com) takes the `Host bitbucket \nHostName bitbucket.org`form.

Comment: [Gitlab also uses the `Host`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html#configure-ssh-to-point-to-a-different-directory) and ignores the `Hostname`. Weird!

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica I expanded my answer to explain this better.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried again and you are right: if the HostName is missing it defaults to the host, but otherwise it is indeed used. When I wrote my previous comment I had probably messed up something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ~/.ssh/[public_key_name] -o IdentitiesOnly=yes'
git clone ...
```